# What is the proper way to implement Form Authentication along side Facebook/Other authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am building an application in ASP.NET MVC 3 in which I have implemented Forms authentication.

I would also like to give the user the option to Sign-up/log-in with their facebook account(and possibly other social accounts in the future.)

I am using the [C# Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

I have successfully implemented the facebook login workflow. Now my question is, how to handle mixing both Forms and Facebook Auth? I can't seem to find any sufficient examples of how to accomplish this.

In regards to my facebook implementation, I am requesting permission from the user for a non-expiring Auth Token which I will store in my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you will have to do something like this

1. Create a custom class (CurrentIdentity) which implements *IIdentity*. Override .ToString() for this class, and so that you have some sort of serialized state of object. I had use "|" seperator. This string will be stored in encrypted cookie.
2. Create a session cookie

   ```
   public static HttpCookie AuthCookie(CurrentIdentity identity) {
      //Create the Authticket, store it in Cookie and redirect user back
      FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                         identity.Name, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(3), true, identity.ToString(), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
      string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
      HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
      authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
      return authCookie;
   }
   ```
3. Add this cookie to response.

   ```
   HttpResponse res = HttpContext.Current.Response;
   res.Cookies.Add(Helper.AuthCookie(identity));
   res.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(identity.Name, true));
   res.End();
   ```
4. Now in Gloabl.asax, inside *Application_AuthenticateRequest* read this cookie and populate your CurrentIdentity object, something like this.

   ```
   if (Request.IsAuthenticated == true) {
           // Extract the forms authentication cookie
           string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
           HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

           if (null == authCookie) {
               // There is no authentication cookie.
               return;
           }
           FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
           try {
               authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
           } catch (Exception) {
               // Log exception details (omitted for simplicity)
               return;
           }

           if (null == authTicket) {
               // Cookie failed to decrypt.
               return;
           }
           // When the ticket was created, the UserData property was assigned a
           // pipe delimited string of role names.
           string[] userInfo = authTicket.UserData.Split('|');

           // Create an Identity object
           FormsIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);
           //Populate CurrentIdentity, from Serialized string
           CurrentIdentity currentIdentity = new CurrentIdentity(userInfo[0], userInfo[1], userInfo[2]);
           System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(currentIdentity, userInfo);
           Context.User = principal;
   }
   ```

This should solve your problem. I have implemented similar thing on my [company's website](http://indigoarchitects.com).

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I will try to sort through everything and get something working.

Answer (score 0):

merge facebook authentication with your forms authentication.
When user login using forms auth you create FormsAuthenticationTicket, when login from facebook also create FormsAuthenticationTicket